Regular expression for Unique Sort finding phone extensions from a multicolumn list
Working within a Google Sheet, I have a list of people's work locations or departments in Columns A or G, their names in Columns B or H, and their extensions in Columns C or I. It is formatted this way to be printed on a single letter-size paper in a practical "two-column" view.
I am using Sort and Unique to list all the four-digit extensions from Column C and Column I to make one flat list of all extensions in Column L, ultimately creating a reverse lookup by extension.
I have the formula working for a single column (Column C or Column I), e.g.: =SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(C3:C,REGEXMATCH(TEXT(C3:C,"0000"),"^(\d{4})$")))) provides the expected results.
However, every attempt to combine the formula with both columns for a single list errors out or fails to give appropriate results.
Current formula attempting: =SORT({UNIQUE(FILTER(C3:C,REGEXMATCH(TEXT(C3:C,"0000"),"^(\d{4})$")))}&{UNIQUE(FILTER(I3:I,REGEXMATCH(TEXT(I3:I,"0000"),"^(\d{4})$")))}).
My results are an eight-digit combination of two different extensions.

I think the trick is to combine the ranges include the range in your original formula rather than trying to combine two instances of your formula:
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER({C3:C;E1:E},REGEXMATCH(TEXT({C3:C;E1:E},"0000"),"^(\d{4})$"))))

Although I think this also works:
=SORT(UNIQUE(CONCAT(
               FILTER(C3:C,REGEXMATCH(TEXT(C3:C,"0000"),"^(\d{4})$")), 
               FILTER(E3:E,REGEXMATCH(TEXT(E3:E,"0000"),"^(\d{4})$"))
)))


Thanks Rufus,
Your the first formula worked with the combined ranges. You rock!

@TruRegnoc Glad it worked! Please mark as answered if that answered the question
